# WordPress: How to echo link URL with post_content in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, url, post

I have a foreach statement going through my posts on WP, with this as my PHP code:

```
echo $post->post_content;
```

The post body has a link:

```
<a href="www.example.com>Example Link</a>
```

Yet when the PHP code runs, it outputs "Example Link" and no link tags or link URL. Is there a way to get the post_content so that all data is returned? Am I using the right call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply the_content filter

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: When you edit the post, looking at the text edit mode, the A tag is there? Maybe, for some reason (some times for tags that is not closed properly) the tag is missing. Paste here your post content

Comment: <a href="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/myPDF.pdf" rel="">Example Link</a>

Comment: There is an extra ";" that probably is causing the problem. Remove this and try again. I think this will work

Comment: I don't know why the extra ";" got inserted when I copied and pasted, it's actually not there.

Comment: OK. When you look at the source code, it shows the text inside the A tag but nothing of the tag?

Comment: Right. In the course code, Only what inside the link tag is showing, not the link tag itself.

Comment: Weird :-/ There is any activated plugin that can mess with the content? Have you tried to do the default wordpress loop instead a foreach?

Comment: Wait, I was looking in the console elements, not the actual source view, it's there.

Comment: Oh, ok. Send me a print of the source code? Probably another tag is broken and causing this.